# Basic webpage css and html not loading

Tags: html, css

hey i am a newbie in HTML world, and i am trying to make a simple html webpage with css in it but the webpage is just blank, please help me outand also there are no error in the console.

linking14.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="C:\Users\Manuj Srivastava\Desktop\html tutorials\css\linking14.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                                        <!relation and accordingly type is set>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1"></div>
        <div id="div2"></div>
        <div id="div3"></div>
        <div id="div4"></div>
        <div id="div5"></div>
        <div id="div6"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and linking14.css

```
#div1{
    width: "300px";
    height: "200px";
    background: "firebrick"; <!#B222222>
} 
#div2{
    width:"300px";
    height:"200px";
    background:"skyblue";     
}
#div3{
    width:"300px";
    height:"200px";
    background:"slateblue";   <!#6A5ACD>
}
#div4{
    width:"300px";
    height:"200px";
    background:"firebrick" ;  <!#87CEEB>
}
#div5{
    width:"300px";
    height:"200px";
    background:"#1BE7FF";
        float:left;
}
#div6{
    width:"300px";
    height:"200px";
    background:"#052633";
        float:left;
}
```

Comment: did you link the css to html?

Comment: did you try to access the css directly from the browser?

Comment: download css, js file from w3cschool and link it to your .html file.  For any problem , refer this link https://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: @SalluSalman yes i did..!!

Comment: @GabrielChiHongLee yes i can access it..!!

Comment: @ManujSrivastava a little tip, don't use spaces in folder names & file names, and remember that if you place your files on a linux environment that everything is case sensitive.

Comment: Add a `<title>`(Your title) `</title>` tag between your `<head>`  `</head>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use quotes `" "` for css properties' values

```css
#div1{
 
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: firebrick;

}

#div2{
    width:300px;
    height: 200px;
    background:skyblue;     
}
#div3{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background:slateblue;   <!#6A5ACD>
}
#div4{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background:firebrick;  <!#87CEEB>
}
#div5{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background:#1BE7FF;
        float:left;
}
#div6{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background:#052633;
        float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"> </div>
    <div id="div2"> </div>
    <div id="div3"> </div>
    <div id="div4"> </div>
    <div id="div5"> </div>
    <div id="div6"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<link href="C:\Users\Manuj Srivastava\Desktop\html tutorials\css\linking14.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

to

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/linking14.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Also, use forward slashes. I would not use spaces in my file names, or directory names. Know what your webroot is. It helps when trying to specify relative paths to resources.

Comment: still nothing on the screen ..!! :(

Comment: code has been updated. please check. backward slash(\\) changed to forward slash (/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<link>
```

This tag's `src` attribute should not use Windows file path conventions. Use a file path that is relative to your web server. I would not use spaces in file names or folders.

```
<link type="text/css" href="css\linking14.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the windows directory structure as the css link like

```
C:\Users\Manuj Srivastava\Desktop\html tutorials\css\linking14.css
```

It should be

```
./css/linking14.css
```

./ is current folder

Answer (score 0):

If your html file is on the same folder of css file, change your link to:

```
<link href="linking14.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

If is on subfolder "css", change your link to:

```
<link href="css/linking14.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that your values for your `CSS` properties are in quotes `""`.

```
#div4{
    width:"300px";
    height:"200px";
    background:"firebrick";
}
```

Needs to be:

```
#div4{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: firebrick;
}
```

Even though your `CSS` file is linked correctly, the `CSS` will not display because the quotes will produce an `invlaid property value` error when the `CSS` is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If this is supposed to be a comment

`<!relation and accordingly type is set>`

it should be

```
<!--relation and accordingly type is set-->
```

And i advice you put all you project files in a Folder for easy linking of `css` , `scripts`, images or nay other files

[read here](https://thehelloworldprogram.com/web-development/creating-files-folder-structure-web-pages/)`

Comment: Yes, code with wrong syntax is generally ignored by HTML but can break it.

Answer (score 0):

Link relatively to a subfolder with the css file and everything will be fine:

```
<link href="css\linking14.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Just make sure linking14.html and css subfolder are in the same folder.

Also remember that this link is case-sensitive so if you name your css file "Linking14.css" you will also have to use capital L in the html file.